# Clang Launch Sequence?

Tags: compiler-construction, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1, llvm-clang

What LLVM/Clang code is executed in what order upon passing source code to Clang for compilation?

Comment: If this is platform and/or IDE-dependent, then I'm asking this question in the context of OS X 10.10 Yosemite and Xcode 6.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean?  Are you interested in compilation phases, or do you want to see a stack trace for a particular method or class?

---

**Compilation phases:**

Let's say you pass some source file to `clang` by typing `clang main.c` into Terminal.

The `clang` command by itself is just a driver which consumes parameters and invokes the actual compiler (you can invoke it directly by passing `clang` the `-cc1` argument).

Then, the compiler itself does the following jobs:

- Invoking the preprocessor to handle all macro definitions (`#define`, `#ifdef`, etc.)
- Breaks all source code into tokens (`if` keyword, `while` keyword, `your_var` identifier, etc.)
- Passes tokens to the parser, which constructs an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and applies semantic analysis, but *only* in place (e.g.: check if assignment expression has correct types for lvalue and rvalue)
- When the AST is done being generated, then the 'CodeGen' phase comes into play:  it translates the AST passed to it by the parser into [LLVM Intermediate Representation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html)
- Here, front-end phase ends and LLVM finally appears:  it takes LLVM IR, applies optimizations and generates assembly code or object files for the end-user platform (e.g.:  x86_64, arm64)

---

**Stacktrace:**

If you want to take a look at a stack trace or debugging report, then it makes sense to build Clang on your own.

Here are instructions for compiling LLVM/Clang on OS X using Xcode after cloning the LLVM repository to your hard drive via Git:

First, download LLVM's source files:

```
mkdir ~/Projects/clang-dev
cd ~/Projects/clang-dev
git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git llvm/tools/clang
git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang-tools-extra.git llvm/tools/clang/tools/extra
git clone http://llvm.org/git/compiler-rt.git llvm/projects/compiler-rt
```

*You can also specify exact version by passing branch name to each clone command, e.g.:
`git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git -b release_34`*

Next, create and open an Xcode project:

```
cd ~/Projects/clang-dev
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G Xcode CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" ../llvm
open LLVM.xcodeproj
```

Set `clang` as your project's current target/scheme, click 'Edit scheme,' and add a source file to be passed to Clang as an argument when it runs:

[image: Edit scheme]

That's pretty much it; just set a breakpoint (in the `main` method or whenever you want) and hit the `Run` button (or press Cmd + R).

**UPD**

Here is more detailed guide: [Getting started with LLVM/Clang on OS X](http://alexdenisov.github.io/blog/getting-started-with-llvm-slash-clang-on-os-x/)

---

Useful Links:

[*Architecture of Open-Source Applications:  LLVM* by Chris Lattner](http://aosabook.org/en/llvm.html)

[*objc.io:  The Compiler* by Chris Eidhof](http://www.objc.io/issue-6/compiler.html)